# Redraw with new properties - Cocoa/Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos

Say that I have this view called "MyView".
And I have these three dropdowns called "Shadow", "Color" and "Border".

Whenever I change one of these dropdowns I want the view to update with the selected property!
How do I do this? I'm currently just able to draw a square in the view :(

Please help me out on this one!

Thank you!

Comment: the view "myView" is inside my main window, the main window holds all the dropdowns.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you change a value - call `[myRectangleView setNeedsDisplay:YES]`. This way your app will know that it needs to redraw the view and once it does - it will use newly set values.

Comment: Note - this is less obvious if you use @synthesize to synthesize your accessors. With synth'd accessors, you don't get the chance to do this. You'll want to write out your accessors long-hand and put the -setNeedsDisplay: call there.

Comment: Really sorry, but how do i reference my view so i can use it in calls? I'm coming from non-OO PHP programming :)

Comment: if you're drawing directly into a view that is being managed through view controller, then probably self.view will do. Not sure about your code so it's kinda hard to tell.